# Sliders in Unity VR

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

We're working on a video player app for the Go. We built a straightforward raycaster script to trigger onClick events when a user points at a UI Button element and pulls the trigger:

```
bool triggerPulled = OVRInput.GetDown(OVRInput.Button.PrimaryIndexTrigger);
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hit, 1000))
    {

        if ( triggerPulled )
        {

            // if we hit a button
            Button button = hit.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<Button>();

            if (button != null)
            {
                button.onClick.Invoke();
            }

        }
....
    }
```

We'd really like to be able to manipulate UI Sliders with the laser pointer as well as buttons, but aren't clear on whether there are analogous events we can trigger for the appropriate behavior. We can call `onValueChanged` to alter the value, but that doesn't really give us the sliding behavior we'd like, only lets us set the new value once we know where we're ending up.

Does anybody have good ideas for how to approach this?

Comment: *"but that doesn't really give us the sliding behavior we'd like, only lets us set the new value once we know where we're ending up."* What do you expect? What's the behavior you are looking for on the Slider?

Comment: Specifically, that you'd be able to point at it, hold the trigger, and slide it back and forth. :) With this code, it doesn't respond at all (since it's not a button).

Comment: You can slide a slider from code with `Silder.value` or with `Slider.onValueChanged`. Not sure what is the exact issue you have.

Comment: Right, you can set the new value (what you'd expect to happen when you release the trigger), but that doesn't account for tracking the slider -- having it follow where you're pointing while you hold the trigger down.

Comment: Hi Sean, the answer I just posted should provide what you were after. You can use the `OVRInputModule` Oculus has written for this purpose. This should also remove the need for you to have a custom script on your button for "clicks" as the `OVRInputModule` should also automatically handle that if set up like in the answer below. Finally, I have put in a simple line for a pointer and a gaze pointer. These can easily be changed / removed if they need to be. They are just there for demonstrational purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Oculus Integration](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/oculus-integration-82022) has a script called `OVRInputModule.cs`. I believe this is designed for what you are trying to do. In order to do this there are a few steps. A GIF of the result.

[image]

To achieve this, I split the code into three scripts; `ControllerInfo`, `ControllerPointer`, and `SetUITransformRay`.

Controller info is just a class that makes sure that scripts always have the correct information.

```
using UnityEngine;
using static OVRInput;

public class ControllerInfo : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform trackingSpace;
    public static Transform TRACKING_SPACE;
    public static Controller CONTROLLER;
    public static GameObject CONTROLLER_DATA_FOR_RAYS;

    private void Start () {
        TRACKING_SPACE = trackingSpace;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        CONTROLLER = ((GetConnectedControllers() & (Controller.LTrackedRemote | Controller.RTrackedRemote) & Controller.LTrackedRemote) != Controller.None) ? Controller.LTrackedRemote : Controller.RTrackedRemote;
    }
}
```

`ControllerPointer` draws a line from the controller. This represents the way the controller is pointing. Add this to a `LineRenderer`.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using static OVRInput;

[RequireComponent(typeof(LineRenderer))]
public class ControllerPointer : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private SetUITransformRay uiRays;
    private LineRenderer pointerLine;
    private GameObject tempPointerVals;

    private void Start()
    {
        tempPointerVals = new GameObject();
        tempPointerVals.transform.parent = transform;
        tempPointerVals.name = "tempPointerVals";
        pointerLine = gameObject.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        pointerLine.useWorldSpace = true;

        ControllerInfo.CONTROLLER_DATA_FOR_RAYS = tempPointerVals;
        uiRays.SetUIRays();
    }

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        Quaternion rotation = GetLocalControllerRotation(ControllerInfo.CONTROLLER);
        Vector3 position = GetLocalControllerPosition(ControllerInfo.CONTROLLER);
        Vector3 pointerOrigin = ControllerInfo.TRACKING_SPACE.position + position;
        Vector3 pointerProjectedOrientation = ControllerInfo.TRACKING_SPACE.position + (rotation * Vector3.forward);
        PointerEventData pointerData = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current);
        Vector3 pointerDrawStart = pointerOrigin - pointerProjectedOrientation * 0.05f;
        Vector3 pointerDrawEnd = pointerOrigin + pointerProjectedOrientation * 500.0f;
        pointerLine.SetPosition(0, pointerDrawStart);
        pointerLine.SetPosition(1, pointerDrawEnd);

        tempPointerVals.transform.position = pointerDrawStart;
        tempPointerVals.transform.rotation = rotation;
    }
}
```

`SetUITransformRay` will automatically set the controller for the `OVRInputModule` ray. It is required as normally you have two controllers in your scene; one for left and one for right. See the full method below for more info on how to set this up. Add this component to your `EventSystem` that is generated when you add a canvas.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class SetUITransformRay : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private OVRInputModule inputModule;
    [SerializeField]
    private OVRGazePointer gazePointer;

    public void SetUIRays()
    {
        inputModule.rayTransform = ControllerInfo.CONTROLLER_DATA_FOR_RAYS.transform;
        gazePointer.rayTransform = ControllerInfo.CONTROLLER_DATA_FOR_RAYS.transform;
    }
}
```

---

**Steps to Use**

Step 1) Scene Setup

Import the Oculus Integration pack. Drag the `OVRCameraRig` onto your scene. Drag a `OVRTrackedRemote` into the left and right hand anchors. Set each remote to left or right depending on the anchor.

[image]

Step 2) Set up your canvas and eventsystem.

On the Canvas,

[image]

On the EventSystem,

[image]

Step 3) Set up correct objects

Create 3 objects; `Controller Manager`, `Controller Pointer`, and `OVRGazePointer`.

For the `OVRGazePointer`, I just quickly went in the example scene for UI, `Oculus\VR\Scenes`, and prefabed the `OVRGazePointer` there.

On Controller Pointer, there is a `LineRenderer`. This has **two** points, doesn't matter where. It **uses world space**. It has a width of 0.005.

Only having two points, and using world space is very **important**. This is because `ControllerPointer` the script relies on those two being set like that.

[image]

Comment: Top notch answer! Thank you for that. I'll dive into giving the Oculus code a go (and, if it isn't already, making it general purpose enough to support the non-Oculus platforms we work with as well).

Comment: @SeanMcMains Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help but I will highly recommend checking these two sdks:

first one is [GoogleVR sdk](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk), you can check there event system and how they implemented their raycast system and integrated it with unity.

the second one is [leap motion interaction engine](https://developer.leapmotion.com/unity#116) in the "Basic UI scene". they have implemented scrollbar using physics so you can interact with it using hands. you can check it I think it will be very useful.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers! After researching further, I think ultimately that writing or adapting an `InputModule` to do what we want (as Google and Leap have done) will indeed be our best bet. I'd just hoped that it would be a common enough modality that someone would have already done it and saved us the effort. :)

Answer (score 0):

I later found this blog post from Oculus that provides some terrific code and examples; it's similar to Dan's answer, but even more thorough and with downloadable examples.

https://developer.oculus.com/blog/easy-controller-selection/